# Skip photo preview when making photos with mobile camera - Cordova(phonegap)

Tags: cordova, camera, phonegap

I'm using Apache Cordova (PhoneGap) in a mobile development app.

The problem i'm having right now is that if i take a picture, i get to see the image that i make with my camera first. It shows 2 option: Ok or Again. I want to skip this photo preview screen and want to trigger the succes-event right away so that i can keep making images as fast as possible whilst still uploading them to the server.

Uploading the image to the server is already working, but does anyone got any idea how to skip the image preview?

I've read the phonegap docs, but i can't seem to find anything. I tried to set allowEdit to false, but this doesn't change anything.

This is my code:

```
var cameraSuccess = function(mediaFiles) {
   formData = new FormData();
   var blob = dataURItoBlob(mediaFiles);

   formData.append('imagedata', blob, 'app.png');

   var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
   request.open("POST", "https://urltomyapi");
   request.send(formData); 
}; 

// capture error callback 
var cameraError = function(error) { 
   navigator.notification.alert('Error code: ' + error.code, null, 
   'Capture Error'); 
}; 

// start video capture 
navigator.camera.getPicture(cameraSuccess, cameraError, { 
   destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
   sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA
});
```